# Select events of upcoming weekend

Tags: mysql

My table has events with start and end dates. I need to select only the events for the coming weekend.

For events of the upcoming week I can just use as it's just the same as the selection for today.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE startdate <= CURDATE() AND enddate >= CURDATE()
```

How can I select only the events for the upcoming weekend?

Comment: Weekend = Saturday + Sunday or something else. And what if today is a weekend?

Comment: If today is saturday or sunday it should include the events as well.

Comment: You can get today date, calculate its weekday (use WEEKDAY() function, it produces the most comfortable weekdays enumeration), then adjust the date up to weekend dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate next Saturday and Sunday using [`weekday`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function and some math:

```
Mon (weekday = 0) => add 5 days to get next Sat
Tue (weekday = 1) => add 4 days to get next Sat
.
.
.
Sun (weekday = 6) => add -1 days to get previous Sat
```

And `where` clause will look like ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)):

```
WHERE current_date + interval (5 - weekday(current_date)) day <= enddate
and   current_date + interval (6 - weekday(current_date)) day >= startdate
```

Answer (score 2):

```
...
WHERE CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (5 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY <= enddate
  AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY >= startdate
```